# Want to understand answer to stars and bars question for coin flips.

Tags: combinatorics

If you flip a coin 18 times and get 14 heads and four tails, what's the probability that there is no pair of consecutive tails? (Want to understand answer)

I know this is a stars and bars problem

The answer is: $\cfrac{\binom{(14-3)+(5-1)}{(14-3)}}{\binom{18}{14}} $

Now I understand the $C(5-1)$ there are 4 tails that act as "bars" to seperate the heads, the "stars".

I understand the $C(18, 14)$ as the denominator, that's simply all possibilities.

What I don't understand is the $C(14-3)$, why subtract by 3?

Thank You for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid sequence will be of the form $$\_TH\_TH\_TH\_T\_$$
where a blank space can hold any number of Heads, or no heads at all.

We have used up $3$ of our heads so far, leaving us with $(14-3)$ heads left over.

We need to assign the remaining Heads to the blanks. With $14-3$ Heads to place, and $5$ blank spaces to choose with replacement, we have the number of ways to do this as $$\binom{(14-3)+5-1}{14-3}$$

Comment: Thank You so much, I didn't think about how there should be 3 heads inbetween them, Thanks again